# Letters in Math mode appear in greek

Tags: beamer, math-mode, greek

I am creating a beamer presentation with main language being greek. When trying to add letters inside a math environment either using `$<math>$` or `\[<math>\]` the letters appear in Greek rather than English. Note that I don't use a `\text{}` command as this would print letters in the main language.

My code is

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\title[\eng{Benchmarking} $^{nat}B(p,p)^{nat}B$]{\smallΈλεγχος Αξιοπιστίας Διαφορικών Ενεργών Διατομών Ελαστικής Σκέδασης Πρωτονίων σε Στόχο Φυσικού
Βορίου}
\author[Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος]{Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}
\institute[Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))]{Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
$p+p$
\[p+p\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You're forgetting `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`

Comment: @egreg : Thank you very much! This really fixed it!

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer>

Comment: I'd rather close it as duplicate